# Accessing the xpath for generlized mixed model using SPSS java plugin

Tags: xpath, spss, mixed-models

I am using SPSS(version 22) java plugin and run a generalized linear mixed model. I wan to get the output of the AIC from the generated output. 
I am not sure what is the xpath of for getting this value?

Can anyone help me write that?

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on the SPSSX-L listserve.  What I posted there:
This should do it, assuming that your OMS request selected just the Goodness of Fit table (oms select tables /if subtypes='GoodnessOfFit'...)
//category[@text="Akaike's Information Criterion (AIC)"]//cell/@number